# How to Change space between series data colums in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

This is not DUPLICATED!!! Sorry if yes.

I want to increase the space between columns independently to the `pointWidth` property and the `#container` width. Please this couple of pictures
and [the fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/tresorunikin/pk57b/)

[image: <code>pointWidth</code>=14]
[image: pointWidth=40]

How can I edit this space/margin/padding ?

Answer (score 2):

In your current chart, the number of bars you have, combined with the fixed `pointWidth` of 14 (pixels) you have set on each series, means that the `groupPadding` setting which you have not set and therefore defaults to 0.2 (x-axis units) is squashing the bar pairs together, overriding any increase you try to set to `pointPadding`.

If you reduce `groupPadding`, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/fKa2y/), the pairs will come apart accordingly. If your number or bars and/or chart width are variable, and you want to fix the ratio of the gaps between points and groups, then set your `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` as required, and remove the fixed `pointWidths` you have specified so that the bar widths take up the slack, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6n6/).

Comment: Thank you very much @storvroz this works of course but I would like to increase the width of the column. The default width is thinner while I would like to have bigger columns. How can I then set the value of the column width?

Comment: In the absence of a set width, the columns will be drawn as wide as can be, given your pointPadding and groupPadding, so reduce them to give you wider columns, [for example](http://jsfiddle.net/LjafL/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointRange / groupPadding / pointPadding, skipping pointWidth.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: Thank you Sebastian but I don't see how apply this to my chart! Can you please edit my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/tresorunikin/pk57b/

Comment: 1) remove all of your 'pointwidth' settings on both the plotOptions and series levels.  2) apply pointRange, pointPadding, and groupPadding settings in the plotOptions.  example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pk57b/1/

Comment: On the other hand, that is a very convoluted chart that, in the end, isn't going to be very helpful in understanding your data.  It appears to be a classic case of trying to cram everything into a single chart, when multiple charts are really the answer.  FWIW